# finding centerline from distance transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

Given a binary input image, I would like to extract the centerline from its distance transform. I have achieved some results, however, I was wondering whether:

1. The whole process can be done more efficiently, i.e. reducing the number of steps, avoiding thresholds, etc.
2. How to recover some regions that I misdetected (gaps in lines), e.g. have a look at the red ellipses in the last image.

[image: Input Image]
[image]
The code is given below:

```
im=im2bw(imread('test.tif'));
figure(1), subplot(3,2,1)
imshow(im,[]);
title('Input Image');

imd=bwdist(~im);
subplot(3,2,2)
imshow(imd,[]);
title('Euclidean Distance Transform');

%imw=watershed(imd);
%imw=imw==0;
log=del2(imd);
subplot(3,2,3)
imshow(log,[]);
title('Laplacian of Gaussian');

imp=bwperim(im);
se=strel('disk',1);
imp=imdilate(imp,se);
subplot(3,2,4)
imshow(imp,[]);
title('Dilated Perimeter');

bin=log < -0.2;
mask=bin-imp;
mask=mask>0;
subplot(3,2,5)
imshow(mask,[]);
title('Binazired mask');

rp = regionprops(mask, 'PixelIdxList', 'Area');
rp = rp(vertcat(rp.Area) > 30);

centerline=zeros(size(im));
centerline(vertcat(rp.PixelIdxList))=1;
centerline=bwmorph(centerline,'thin');
subplot(3,2,6)
imshow(centerline,[]);
title('Final mask');
```

The steps of the algorithm is as follows:

- Compute the Distance Transform from the binary image.
- Apply the Laplacian of Gaussian. I would expect large negative values on the centerline.
- Threshold responses of the LoG, remove pixels on the boundaries of the original binary image and keep lines that have a length of at least 30 pixels.

Comment: Why misdetected? They look pretty good for me. You mean fill the gap in the lines?

Comment: You could perhaps fill in the gaps by applying a Hough transform.

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes, fill the gaps in the lines, and also don't like the "many" steps I'm doing.

Comment: Those many steps also look quite reasonable

Comment: @rayryeng, do you have an illustration? on the other hand, using the HT will create straight lines only, right? However, in my case, the lines are not necessarily straight ;-)

Comment: morphological operations can help in connecting the pixels in very close range but am not sure weather if will be able to solve your problem. my suggestion would be to use it on the final three images individually and see if it works. also play with the kernel sizes, it might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Medial Axis from skimage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#medial-axis)